# How can I know my Node.JS application security is up to standard?

Tags: node.js, security

I'm currently develop a Node.JS application for bank. I always put up security as part of my concern while developing, so I ensure all the data is encrypted. But I still afraid it might not enough. How can I know my Node.JS application is up to standard? Is there any guideline or tools to tell me this?
I appreciate your sharing your thought with me.

Many Thanks~~~

Comment: This is a super broad question that has no generic answer.  It depends entirely upon the details of your application, what it does, how you're written it, how it's deployed, what you're protecting, etc...

Comment: hi jfriend00, thx for your comment. My application is not dealing with any confidential data. It mean for monitoring the audio visual system, room booking system, the only credible data would be the LDAP, which I already did LDAPS for more secure method, my worry is, will my application create a backdoor for hacker to gain access to other confidential data, since my server is going to sit on their network.

Comment: Sorry if your question is being downvoted, but this is a handbook bad question for SO. Here's some [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) about this topic. Someone took the time and wrote some hints already, but this question is more then likely being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Security is really hard to get right. There are so many different factors to consider, countless different ways to break an application.*

This guide is definitely not meant to address every single possible security flaw within application. It does, however, provide a basic checklist to ensure that an **Express** application addresses or application some of the biggest security threats.

1. Enable TLS/SSL
2. Encode All Untrusted Data Sent to an Application
3. HTML Encoding
4. Prevent Parameter Pollution to Stop Possible Uncaught Exceptions
5. Add Helmet to Set Sane Defaults
6. Block Cross-Site Request Forgeries
7. Brute Force Protection
8. Command Injection
9. Don't Use Evil Regular Expressions
   and many more you can see below link

[node secuirty tips](https://nodesource.com/blog/nine-security-tips-to-keep-express-from-getting-pwned/)

[node playback](https://github.com/HiFaraz/node-playbook)

[Node Secuirty check](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/)